# How can I get the event.target.id from a click on the text in a table cell using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, function, html-table, bind

I have a somewhat simple HTML table with the code

```
<table><tr><td id=tdFavicon><b>Favicon</b></td></tr></table>
```

and I want to bind an event to it using the code

```
$(tdFavicon).bind('click', saveOption);
```

but my problem is when I use the code

```
function saveOption() {alert(event.target.id);}
```

I get only the id "tdFavicon" alerted when the cell is clicked, and not when the text in the cell is clicked.

It seems to me that this should work, but maybe my code has become too complex.  I changed it for this example.  I could maybe make a span with an id for the text inside the table cell to bind to, but I would like to know why this is not working.  Can anyone help me make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event's bubble. That is when you click an element, it looks for a click handler on that element. If it doesn't find one it looks on the parent element, then the parent's parent, all the way up to the root element.

So `event.target` is the element that generated the event (the `<b>` tag), but NOT the element that handled it (the `<td id="tdFavicon">` tag). jQuery provides the element that *handled* the event as the context of the called handler function (the value of `this`).

Which means, all you need to do is this:

```
function saveOption() {
    alert(this.id);
}
$('#tdFavicon').bind('click', saveOption);
```

Or perhaps more simply:

```
$('#tdFavicon').bind('click', function {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

[Proof it works](http://jsfiddle.net/w7xEN/2/)

Comment: This makes sense too.  I think I was expecting to get the "this" data in the saveOption function, but it was not passed, because I used a generic function in the bind portion of the code (which then I would have needed to send manually as you showed above)!  Because I wasn't getting the "this" data, I was trying to access the event.target.id information, which there was none.  I was trying to do it without having to pass extra variables manually to the receiving function.

Answer (score 2):

try this (note: although using `$(tdFavicon)` might work, it is not guaranteed, and it is also slower than using the selector `"#tdFavicon"`.)

```
$("#tdFavicon").bind('click', function(ev){
 saveOption(this,ev);
});

function saveOption(elem,ev) {
 alert("table cell: " + elem.id + "  object clicked: " + ev.target.tagName);
}
```

The reason your code was not working was that the event from the click was actually on the text element, so that was what you got - an empty id. All in all your code ran just fine, it just had a logical error.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense.  But, is there a way to know what kind of HTMLElement object this is using alert(event.?????) without explicitly specifying an id or type for the text element in the table cell?  So that I can know it was sent from a text element and not something else.

Comment: @theMaxx - See edit in function, it should alert the html element. You have to pass the event into the function to be able to use it.